# error message saying missing value where true/false is needed, but i don't see where the missing value comes from

Tags: r

i keep getting the error message for my while statement at the end, but I don't see why there is a missing value in this statement. Should be a simple statement,but I am not sure why it is not working. Can someone please help me on that?

```
y = c(0.9683, 0.4515, 17.4488, 0.6287, 2.2330, 2.6467, 3.9589, 0.0782, 5.4717, 4.1161, 0.6715, 1.6350, 0.1640, 0.3331, 0.7501, 3.0846, 0.6889, 6.3826, 7.0869, 0.7967, 3.2684,0.1373, 2.8698, 1.5126, 0.9055)

x = c(0.1036, 2.1824, 0.1745, 2.0089, 1.2317, 0.6166, 0.4675, 3.2074, 0.0277, 1.2962, 0.6812, 0.1946, 1.3291, 0.4381, 0.2984, 0.3018, 0.7928, 0.2021, 1.0280, 0.0121, 1.2043, 2.9322, 1.4526, 0.6444, 0.1849)


score = function(b0,b1) {
i = 1:25
score1 = sum(-y[i]+(b0+b1*x[i])^-1)
score2 = sum(-y[i]*x[i]+x[i]*(b0+b1*x[i])^-1)

scorevector = c(score1,score2)
scorematrix = cbind(c(score1,score2))

scorematrix
}


jb = function(b0,b1) {
i=1:25

jb11 = sum((b0+b1*x[i])^{-2})
jb12 = sum(x[i]/(b0+b1*x[i])^{2})
jb21 = sum(x[i]/(b0+b1*x[i])^{2})
jb22 = sum(x[i]^{2}/(b0+b1*x[i])^{2})


jbmatrix = cbind(c(jb11,jb21),c(jb12,jb22))
jbmatrixinv = (1/(jb11*jb22-jb21*jb12))*cbind(c(jb22,-jb21),c(-jb12,jb11))

jbmatrixinv
}

bold = cbind(c(1,1)) ; bnew = cbind(c(2,2))
track = c(bnew[1,1],bnew[2,1])

while ((bnew[1,1]-bold[1,1])^2+(bnew[2,1]-bold[2,1])^2 > 10^{-6}) {
  
  bold = bnew
  bnew = bold + jb(bold[1,1],bold[2,1]) %*% score(bold[1,1],bold[2,1])
  track = rbind(track, c(bnew[1,1],bnew[2,1]))
}

Error in while ((bnew[1, 1] - bold[1, 1])^2 + (bnew[2, 1] - bold[2, 1])^2 >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

[image]

Comment: Just get rid of the `{}` brackets around the `-6`?

Comment: i tried it, but still have that message.

Comment: What is the value of the LHS?

Comment: Yes sorry I see that the `{}` don't cause any problem. The problem is that the value of b exceeds the maximum for double precision values after 9 or 10 iterations. So you get a `NaN` value which results in a missing value at the next time `while` evaluates the condition. Take a look at your `track` object. Can you change your calculation to work with logarithms instead, to avoid this issue?

Comment: what are you referring to for LHS? @RuiBarradas

Comment: left hand side value is just a constant that is from the calculation. @RuiBarradas

Comment: do i need to change all the values to log()? @qdread

Comment: The left hand side is not constant, both `bold` and `bnew` will vary in the `while` loop. The LHS grows until it becomes `NaN`, and the condition `NaN > 10^(-6)` is now `NA`. The last value before the code breaks is `1.442032e+213`.

Comment: basically i am trying to find a bnew vector that the difference between the new value and the previous value is <10^(-6), so bnew=(b'0,b'1), bold = (b0,b1), i want (b'0-b0)^2 + (b'1-b1)^2 < 10^(-6) that is what the while statement is referring to. if the difference is bigger than that, i do bnew = bold + inverse of the information matrix * score vector to get a new bnew and compare it with the previous vector. that is what I am trying to do with the loop. not sure why the difference is getting bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what is said in comment, the left hand side is not constant, both `bold` and `bnew` will vary in the `while` loop. The LHS grows until it becomes `NaN`, and the condition `NaN > 10^(-6)` is now `NA`. The last value before the code breaks is `1.442032e+213`.

I have rewritten the loop's first few instructions to have the LHS value be printed. As you can see it grows very quickly and breaks the code at the 9th iteration. And the growth comes from function `jb`. That's what you have to solve.

```r
iter <- 0L
while (TRUE) {
  
  iter <- iter + 1L
  aux <- (bnew[1,1]-bold[1,1])^2 + (bnew[2,1]-bold[2,1])^2
  cat("iter:", iter, "\taux:", aux, "\n")
  
  if(!(aux > 10^{-6})) break
  
  bold = bnew
  bnew = bold + jb(bold[1,1],bold[2,1]) %*% score(bold[1,1],bold[2,1])
  track = rbind(track, c(bnew[1,1],bnew[2,1]))
}
#> iter: 1  aux: 2 
#> iter: 2  aux: 436.0846 
#> iter: 3  aux: 1754199 
#> iter: 4  aux: 5.234798e+13 
#> iter: 5  aux: 1.291931e+28 
#> iter: 6  aux: 7.904304e+56 
#> iter: 7  aux: 2.959099e+114 
#> iter: 8  aux: 1.442032e+213 
#> iter: 9  aux: NaN
#> Error in if (!(aux > 10^{: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>